# How to set maximum length of characters in entry widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problem related to set a maximum length of characters including spaces, for an entry widget in Tkinter (Python). i have used the concept of bind method but didnot find any solution.
Help me to find a solution for this

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446553/tkinter-entry-character-limit/39063679