# How to limit the character in Entry

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I need to limit the entry to a maximum of 5 digits.

```
def validate(S):
    try:
        float(S)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Datos erroneos, únicamente números.", title="ERROR")
        return False

e1 = tk.Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(validate), '%S'))
```

I have this method to receive and validate that it's just numbers at the entry, but i would like to know how can I put a max limit of 5 digits on the entry.

I tried with the methods used in this question ([Tkinter entry character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446553/tkinter-entry-character-limit)) but it is not working with the validate method.

Comment: Doesn't provide `%i` the information needed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return False from validate if the length of the string is more than 5.

```
def validate(S):
    try:
        float(S)
        return len(S) <= 5
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Datos erroneos, únicamente números.", title="ERROR")
        return False
```